# How can I find out where GRUB was installed?

Tags: hard-drive, grub2, boot-loader

I need to find where GRUB was installed, for example, which drive/partition. Is it possible to figure out where it was installed?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you might talk about.

Comment: I thought the title is descriptive enough, I did not want to write the same thing again for the content. Sorry for that. I correct my fault.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [Boot Info Script](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/):

```
# ./boot_info_script.sh 

boot_info_script version: 0.60        [17 May 2011]

Identifying MBRs...
Computing Partition Table of /dev/sda...
Computing Partition Table of /dev/sdb...
Searching sda1 for information... 
Searching sda2 for information... 
Searching sda3 for information... 
Searching sdb1 for information... 

Finished. The results are in the file "RESULTS.txt"
located in "/root/".
```

and the results:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub Legacy0.97 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    178241 on boot drive #1 for the stage2 file.  A stage2 file is at this 
    location on /dev/sda.  Stage2 looks on partition #1 for /grub/grub.conf..
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

Comment: +1 for superb analytical skill

Comment: Life saver tool.. Finaly I can sleep tonite :)

Comment: There seems to be a new maintainer for this project here: https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript